# Could you check what the problem is when making dual y axis here?

Tags: r, ggplot2, draw, yaxis

```
g <- ggplot(juho, aes(x = year, y= Nationwide)) +
geom_line(linetype = "solid", size = 1, colour = "black") +
geom_point(size =3, colour ="black") +
ggtitle("전체 사교육비 및 1인당 사교육비 연간 추이")

gg <- g + 
geom_line(data=juho, aes(x=year, y= Per * max(juho$Nationwide)/max(juho$Per))+
scale_y_continuous( sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *  (max(juho$Per)/ max(juho$Nationwide)), name = 
"Percapita"))

gg
```

Could you check what the problem is when making dual y-axis?
I saw this error.

> **Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (13): x**

Comment: My recommendation is to not use ggplot if you want to create 2 y-axes.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).